# Codeigniter session id dropped on post

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, post

Everytime I register or delete a user (do anything that involves a post) My Codeigniter session user id gets dropped. I'm using codeigniter 3.0.6

Here is my config.php for session:
`$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
     $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
     $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
     $config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
     $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
     $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
     $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;`

```
  `$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
   $config['cookie_domain'] = 'localhost'; //this used to be mysite.space
   $config['cookie_path']       = '/';
   $config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
   $config['cookie_httponly']   = FALSE;`
```

You can see a before and after below:

[After login I set this->session->userdata in the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V88f3.png)

[after post and return to dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNmpo.png)

The session id gets to the controller but drops/disappears between the controller and model. WHen the DB Post/delete action happens Im redirected this->load->view back to the dashboard and the session id is gone.
please help!

I set the session userdata in the model. And I am loading the session in the $autoload['libraries'] autoload.php

Heres my controller:

```
      `public function login()
    {
        if($this->User->login($this->input->post())){
        $my_trips = $this->User->get_my_trips();
        $userp = $this->User->get_dash_user_info();
        $this->load->view('/dashboard', array("user"=>$userp,                  

    'my_trips'=>$my_trips));
       } else {
          redirect('/');
       }
    }`
```

Heres model:
    
        `$this->form_validation->set_rules("username", "Username", "trim|required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");
        // END VALIDATION RULES
        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
             $this->session->set_flashdata("errors", validation_errors());
             return FALSE;
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
            $values = array($post['username'], $post['password']);
            $user = $this->db->query($query, $values)->row_array();
            if(empty($user)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', '<p id='error'>The username or password you entered is invalid.</p>');
                return FALSE;
            } else {
              $this->session->set_userdata('id', $user['id']);
               return TRUE;
            }`

Comment: Post your controller & model code plz

Comment: added controller and model. And I just tested it. If I switch between dashboard and comments it loses the user ID.